# icon on pressed function isnt working,whenever i click on any icon,i want to show any action there,what to do?

Tags: flutter, dart

please help me. when ever I clicked on home icon it does not show any action however I  applied on pressed function. icon on pressed function is not working, whenever I click on any icon, I want to show any action there, what to do???. I want to show any action there, what to do???. I want to show any action there, what to do???

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'screen_two.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "Screens",
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
          home: LocationApp(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class LocationApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LocationAppState createState() => _LocationAppState();
    }
    
    class _LocationAppState extends State<LocationApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.1),
                    offset: Offset(15.0, 20.0),
                    blurRadius: 20.0,
                  )
                ],
                color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.8),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.settings,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 131.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0, bottom: 30.0),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 130.0,
                              height: 130.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('images/she.png'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  width: 4.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Alisa",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "22 want | 35 done",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                CustomTile(
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.chat_bubble_outline,
                                      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                                    ),
                                    "Order",
                                    () => {},
                                    ""),
                                CustomTile(
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.trip_origin_outlined,
                                      color: Colors.pink,
                                    ),
                                    "Like",
                                    () => {},
                                    "new"),
                                CustomTile(
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                    ),
                                    "Comment",
                                    () {},
                                    ""),
                                CustomTile(
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.android_rounded,
                                      color: Colors.pink,
                                    ),
                                    "Download",
                                    () => {},
                                    ""),
                                CustomTile(
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.zoom_out_sharp,
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                    ),
                                    "Edit", () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => Secondscreen()));
                                }, ""),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 70,
                            color: Colors.black26.withOpacity(0.1),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 0.0,
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    IconButton(
                                      iconSize: 25.0,
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.add_chart,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                    ),
                                    Text('TIPS',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 10)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    IconButton(
                                      iconSize: 25.0,
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.home,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                                        print('Menu Icon pressed');
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Home',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    IconButton(
                                      iconSize: 25.0,
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.person,
                                          color: Colors.red),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      tooltip: '',
                                    ),
                                    Text('Profile',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.red, fontSize: 10)),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen_two.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Screens",
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      home: LocationApp(),
    );
  }
}

class LocationApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationAppState createState() => _LocationAppState();
}

class _LocationAppState extends State<LocationApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    return Scaffold(
      key:_scaffoldKey,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.1),
                offset: Offset(15.0, 20.0),
                blurRadius: 20.0,
              )
            ],
            color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.8),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 131.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0, bottom: 30.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 130.0,
                          height: 130.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('images/she.png'),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 4.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Alisa",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "22 want | 35 done",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            CustomTile(
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.chat_bubble_outline,
                                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                                ),
                                "Order",
                                () => {},
                                ""),
                            CustomTile(
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.trip_origin_outlined,
                                  color: Colors.pink,
                                ),
                                "Like",
                                () => {},
                                "new"),
                            CustomTile(
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star,
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                ),
                                "Comment",
                                () {},
                                ""),
                            CustomTile(
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.android_rounded,
                                  color: Colors.pink,
                                ),
                                "Download",
                                () => {},
                                ""),
                            CustomTile(
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.zoom_out_sharp,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                ),
                                "Edit", () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Secondscreen()));
                            }, ""),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 70,
                        color: Colors.black26.withOpacity(0.1),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 0.0,
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  iconSize: 25.0,
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.add_chart,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                ),
                                Text('TIPS',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 10)),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  iconSize: 25.0,
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.home,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
    ),print('Menu Icon pressed');
                                  },
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Home',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  iconSize: 25.0,
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.person,
                                      color: Colors.red),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  tooltip: '',
                                ),
                                Text('Profile',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.red, fontSize: 10)),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

    Add a scaffold key
Then use the key to open the drawer
```

Comment: In order to really help, you should provide a bit of explanation of how this code works and what was changed.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your print msg print on the terminal or log while pressing on IconButton

Like this code,

```
IconButton(
   iconSize: 25.0,
   icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
   onPressed: () {
   print('Menu Icon pressed');
   },
),
```

The below code will help you to Open drawer,

declare and define scaffold key then also define drawer,
I hope the below code will help you, keep Fluttering :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OpenDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const OpenDrawer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpenDrawerState createState() => _OpenDrawerState();
}

class _OpenDrawerState extends State<OpenDrawer> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      drawer: Drawer(child: YourDrawerWidget()),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            iconSize: 25.0,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.home,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              globalKey.currentState.openDrawer();
              print('Menu Icon pressed');
            },
          ),
          Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```